# Error Query Builder Join in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-query-builder, eloquent

In my Controller

```
$thread = DB::table('threads')
         ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'threads.user_id')
         ->select('users.name')
         ->orderBy('threads.id', 'DESC')
        ->get();

 return view('thread.index', compact('thread'));
```

In my index.blade

```
@foreach($thread as $item)
                  <td> {{ $item->thread }} </td>
                  <td> {{ $item->deskripsi }} </td>
                   <td> <p> Oleh : {{ $item->user_id }}</p> </td>
                      <td>  {{ $item->created_at->diffForHumans() }} </td>

  @endforeach
```

and error

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$thread (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Aplikasi_Kelas_Server\resources\views\thread\index.blade.php)
```

Have any solution? I want to user_id show become name in table users

Comment: Can you show us the content of `$thread`?

Comment: You're not actually using `Eloquent` here.

Comment: yeah i'm sorry. Its Query Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling some property like `thread`, `deskripsi`

```
<td> {{ $item->thread }} </td>
<td> {{ $item->deskripsi }} </td>
```

But you did not select it by your query. you only selects the `name`!! So add the additional column in your query like-

```
$thread = DB::table('threads')
         ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'threads.user_id')
         ->select('users.name', 'threads.thread', 'threads.deskripsi')
         ->orderBy('threads.id', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

Comment: thanks it work ! I only change in users.name become users.*

Comment: just be careful sometimes you may have same column name in both table then with wild card(*) you will get error. e.g if users have a column `name` and threads also have a column named `name` then `users.*, threads.*` will raise error.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the relationship you defined in your models. if users have threads then you should just retrieve the users you want and send the to blade with compact. Use this function in your User model

```
 public function getThreads()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Threads::class);
    }
```

and if your relationships are correct you should be able to get the threads in your blade with this :

```
@foreach($users as $user)
      @foreach($user->getThreads as $thread)
                  <td> {{ $thread->thread }} </td>
                  <td> {{ $thread->deskripsi }} </td>
                  <td> <p> Oleh : {{ $thread->user_id }}</p> </td>
                  <td>  {{ $thread->created_at->diffForHumans() }} </td>
      @endforeach 
@endforeach
```